# Reliability in storm

Tags: apache-storm

I was reading https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v0.9.7/docs/Guaranteeing-message-processing.md#what-is-storms-reliability-api. I had few doubts in Reliability mechanism of Storm (v0.9.4 and 0.9.5) ( I could not find docs for exact versions I needed)

- Does calling `ack()` or `fail()` on an unanchored tuple serve any purpose. Or is it a no-op?
- Do we need to **ack**\ **fail** the tuples in the any bolt receiving tuples directly from a spout ? Assume the spout emits using `public List<Integer> emit(List<Object> tuple,Object messageId)` method.